# Unusual Integral with limits as transcendental roots of exponential equation

Tags: calculus, integration

I encountered difficulties with the integral below.
Let  $h \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$ and let $\xi^{-}(h)$ and $\xi^{+}(h)$ be the respective negative and positive solutions of
$$ e^{\xi} -\xi -1 = h$$

1. Calculate the integral $I(\xi, h)$ with $\xi^{-} \le \xi \le \xi^{+}$
   $$ I(\xi,h )=\int _{\xi ^{-} }^{\xi }\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(h+1+x)^{2} - e^{2x} } }$$
2. Calculate $I(h)$ when $\xi = \xi^{+}(h) $

Note that when $\xi \ll 1$ then $I(h) = \pi$ .
Also when $h \gg 1$ , then $ I(h) \cong \xi^{+}(h) - \xi^{-}(h) +\ln(2)$

Comment: What is your problem ? $\xi$ or the integral ?

Comment: The problem is the integral.  $\xi^{-}$ and $\xi^{+}$ are just the limits of the integral . $\xi$ is a floating variable comprised between these 2 respectively negative and positive values.

Comment: I'd be astonished if $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(h+1+x)^2-e^{2x}}}$ has an easy antiderivative. Without one, since the bounds are variable, specific methods like contour integration are not available...

Comment: It may help to use the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac1{\sqrt{s^2-a^2}},\frac1{\sqrt{s-a}}$ and get $\int_{\xi^-}^{\xi^+}\int_0^\infty I_0(te^x)e^{-(x+h+1)t}dtdx=\int_{\xi^-}^{\xi^+}\int_0^\infty t^{-\frac12}e^{t(h+x+1)^2}e^{-te^{2x}}dtdx$ with the [Bessel I](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselI.html) function.

Comment: @TymaGaidash : thank you . I tried the Laplace transform already. It becomes untractable.

Comment: @TymaGaidash: one can also expand the square root by a binomial expansion in $e^{2x}/(h+x+1)^{2}$ and get a very slowly converging series of Exponential Integrals. Not very satisfactory.